# Share to Facebook wall without pop up dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm building a Facebook app in Rails, where a user creates an entry and submits it into a collection of entries from other users - what I would like to do is have a link to that entry automatically shared to the user's wall on submit, but I can't make sense of the Graph API documentation to do that without a dialog window popping up. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `POST` to a user's `feed` using the Graph API. The [documentation is here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts). You need to request the `publish_stream` permission from your user when they log in.

In this case, your URL will be: `https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_ID/feed` where if you were going to post on Mark Zuckerberg's wall, `USERNAME_OR_ID` would equal `zuck` or `4`. Check out [Net:HTTPSession](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to POST in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is removing the possibility to to post onto the wall of friends, so if you're not just posting to the users own wall remember that as it will go away fairly soon.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

> Post to friends wall via the API generate a high levels of negative user feedback, including “Hides” and “Mark as Spam" and so we are removing it from the API. If you want to allow people to post to their friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag).