# Auto sharing in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share the text and image in face book. Without showing the popup window. While i click the button automatically the text and image will be post in face book who is login in that browser.I got the api from [Here](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/). It working, but i don't want popup window, Sharing will work automatically using php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share to Facebook wall without pop up dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110744/share-to-facebook-wall-without-pop-up-dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you want to achieve (prefilling the message and autoposting) is not allowed on Facebook. You may want to read the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

That being said, the only way to post without a dialog is to use the /me/feed endpoint after authorizing a user with the `publish_actions` permission. Example code can be found in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed#publish

`publish_actions` needs to get approved by Facebook before users can use it, and you will never get it approved for prefilling the message and autoposting: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

**Side note: That article of yours is from 2011. That´s like a hundred years ago in internet time...a lot of stuff in that tutorial is completely outdated. Always use the official docs instead of old articles.**